# Buttons on second html file not working for Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

Ok so I have two html files. base.html and search_results.html

base.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
    body {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        background-image: url('/static/Flat-Color-Gradient-Triangles.png');
        width: 430px;
        height: 763px;
        align-items: center;
    }

    h1 {
        font-family: "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
     font-size: 45px;
        font-color: #333333;
     font-weight: bold;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 3px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    h2 {
        font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
     font-size: 15px;
     font-weight: bold;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 3px;
        border: 1.5px
    }

    h3 {
     font-family: Candara, Calibri, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, Arial, sans-serif;
     font-size: 14px;
     font-weight: 100;
        margin: 0;
        border-top: 1px;
        border-bottom: 1px;
        padding: 3px;
    }

    .explicit{
        color: rgb(200, 0, 0);
    }

    .rank{
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        padding: 4px;
    }

    table, th, td {
        padding: 5px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
    }

    th {
        background-color: #121f1f;
        border-left: #121f1f;
        border-right:#121f1f;
    }

    td {
        background-color: #253f3f;
        border-left: #253f3f;
        border-right: #253f3f;

    }

    input[type='text'] {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 6px 10px;
        margin: 6px 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 2px solid #ccc;
        font-size: 14px;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }

    input[type='text']:focus {
        border: 3px solid red;
    }

    input[type = 'submit'] {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 16px 32px;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin: 4px 2px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    input[value="Up"] {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 16px 32px;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin: 4px 2px;
    }

    input[value="Down"] {
        background-color: rgb(200,0,0);
        border: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 16px 32px;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin: 4px 2px;
    }

    input[value="Add"] {
        border: 3px solid #4CAF50;
        color: white;
        padding: 16px 32px;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin: 4px 2px;
    }

    div.content {
        width: 430px;
        align-items: center;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">
<h1>Public Playlist</h1>


<form action = '/search_results' method="POST">
    <input placeholder="Artist:" type = 'text' name='artist'> </input>
    <input placeholder="Album:" type = 'text' name='album'> </input>
    <input placeholder="Track:" type = 'text' name='track'> </input>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit!" id="search"/>
</form>

<table >
    <tr>
       <th><h2>Rank</h2></th>
       <th><h2>Title</h2>
           <h2>Author|Album</h2></th>
       <th><h2>Score</h2></th>
       <th><h2>Vote</h2></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td><h3 type="bold">1</h3></td>
       <td><h3>{{name}}</h3>
           <h3>{{artist}}:{{album}}</h3></td>
       <td><h3>{{ score }}</h3></td>
        <form action="/vote" method="POST">
             <td>
                 <input type="button" name="vote" value="Up" id="up">
                 <input type="button" name= "vote" value="Down" id="down">
             </td>
        </form>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td><h3 type="bold">2</h3></td>
       <td><h3>{{name1}}</h3>
           <h3>{{artist1}}:{{album1}}</h3></td>
       <td><h3>{{ score1 }}</h3></td>
        <form action="/" method="POST">
             <td>
                 <input type="button" name="vote1" value="Up" id="up">
                 <input type="button" name= "vote1" value="Down" id="down">
             </td>
        </form>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td><h3 type="bold">3</h3></td>
       <td><h3>{{name2}}</h3>
           <h3>{{artist2}}:{{album2}}</h3></td>
       <td><h3>{{ score2 }}</h3></td>
        <form action="/vote" method="POST">
             <td>
                 <input type="button" name="vote2" value="Up" id="up">
                 <input type="button" name= "vote2" value="Down" id="down">
             </td>
        </form>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td><h3 type="bold">4</h3></td>
       <td><h3>{{name3}}</h3>
           <h3>{{artist3}}:{{album3}}</h3></td>
       <td><h3>{{ score3 }}</h3></td>
        <form action="/vote" method="POST">
             <td>
                 <input type="button" name="vote3" value="Up" id="up">
                 <input type="button" name= "vote3" value="Down" id="down">
             </td>
        </form>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td><h3 type="bold">5</h3></td>
       <td><h3>{{name4}}</h3>
           <h3>{{artist4}}:{{album4}}</h3></td>
       <td><h3>{{ score4 }}</h3></td>
        <form action="/vote" method="POST">
             <td>
                 <input type="button" name="vote4" value="Up" id="up">
                 <input type="button" name= "vote4" value="Down" id="down">
             </td>
        </form>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td><h3 type="bold">6</h3></td>
       <td><h3>{{name5}}</h3>
           <h3>{{artist5}}:{{album5}}</h3></td>
       <td><h3>{{ score5 }}</h3></td>
        <form action="/vote" method="POST">
             <td>
                 <input type="button" name="vote5" value="Up" id="up">
                 <input type="button" name= "vote5" value="Down" id="down">
             </td>
        </form>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td><h3 type="bold">7</h3></td>
       <td><h3>{{name6}}</h3>
           <h3>{{artist6}}:{{album6}}</h3></td>
       <td><h3>{{ score6 }}</h3></td>
        <form action="/vote" method="POST">
             <td>
                 <input type="button" name="vote6" value="Up" id="up">
                 <input type="button" name= "vote6" value="Down" id="down">
             </td>
        </form>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td><h3 type="bold">8</h3></td>
       <td><h3>{{name7}}</h3>
           <h3>{{artist7}}:{{album7}}</h3></td>
       <td><h3>{{ score7 }}</h3></td>
        <form action="/vote" method="POST">
             <td>
                 <input type="button" name="vote7" value="Up" id="up">
                 <input type="button" name= "vote7" value="Down" id="down">
             </td>
        </form>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td><h3 type="bold">9</h3></td>
       <td><h3>{{name8}}</h3>
           <h3>{{artist8}}:{{album8}}</h3></td>
       <td><h3>{{ score8 }}</h3></td>
        <form action="/vote" method="POST">
             <td>
                 <input type="button" name="vote8" value="Up" id="up">
                 <input type="button" name= "vote8" value="Down" id="down">
             </td>
        </form>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td><h3 type="bold">10</h3></td>
       <td><h3>{{name9}}</h3>
           <h3>{{artist9}}:{{album9}}</h3></td>
       <td><h3>{{ score9 }}</h3></td>
        <form action="/vote" method="POST">
             <td>
                 <input type="button" name="vote9" value="Up" id="up">
                 <input type="button" name= "vote9" value="Down" id="down">
             </td>
        </form>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>
setTimeout(function () {location.reload() },60000);
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

search_results.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: sans-serif;
      background-image: url('/static/Flat-Color-Gradient-Triangles.png');
      width: 640px;
      height: 1136px;
    }
    h1 {
      font-family: "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
      font-size: 45px;
      font-color: #333333;
      font-weight: bold;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 3px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    h2 {
      font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
      font-size: 15px;
      font-weight: bold;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 3px;
      border: 1.5px
    }
    h3 {
      font-family: Candara, Calibri, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: 100;
      margin: 0;
      border-top: 1px;
      border-bottom: 1px;
      padding: 3px;
    }
    .explicit {
      color: rgb(200, 0, 0);
    }
    .rank {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      padding: 4px;
    }
    table,
    th,
    td {
      padding: 5px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid black;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
    }
    th {
      background-color: #121f1f;
      border-left: #121f1f;
      border-right: #121f1f;
    }
    td {
      background-color: #253f3f;
      border-left: #253f3f;
      border-right: #253f3f;
    }
    input[type='text'] {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 6px 10px;
      margin: 6px 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border: 2px solid #ccc;
      font-size: 14px;
      border-radius: 10px;
    }
    input[type='text']:focus {
      border: 3px solid red;
    }
    input[type='submit'] {
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      border: none;
      color: white;
      padding: 16px 32px;
      text-decoration: none;
      margin: 4px 2px;
      width: 100%;
    }
    input[value="Up"] {
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      border: none;
      color: white;
      padding: 16px 32px;
      text-decoration: none;
      margin: 4px 2px;
    }
    input[value="Down"] {
      background-color: rgb(200, 0, 0);
      border: none;
      color: white;
      padding: 16px 32px;
      text-decoration: none;
      margin: 4px 2px;
    }
    input[name="Add"] {
      border: 3px solid #4CAF50;
      color: white;
      background-color: #253f3f;
      padding: 16px 32px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-weight: bold;
      margin: 4px 2px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Public Playlist</h1>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <h2>Rank</h2>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <h2>Author|Album</h2>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h2>Score</h2>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h2>Add</h2>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <form action="/add" method="GET">
        <td>
          <h3 type="bold">1</h3>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h3>{{name}}</h3>
          <h3>{{artist}}:{{album}}</h3>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h3>{{ score }}</h3>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="button" name="Add" value="Add" id="Add">
        </td>
      </form>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <form action="/add" method="GET">
        <td>
          <h3 type="bold">2</h3>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h3>{{name1}}</h3>
          <h3>{{artist1}}:{{album1}}</h3>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h3>{{ score1 }}</h3>
        </td>

        <td>
          <input type="button" name="Add" value="Add1" id="Add1">
        </td>
      </form>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <form action="/add" method="GET">

        <td>
          <h3 type="bold">3</h3>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h3>{{name2}}</h3>
          <h3>{{artist2}}:{{album2}}</h3>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h3>{{ score2 }}</h3>
        </td>

        <td>
          <input type="button" name="Add" value="Add2" id="Add2">
        </td>
      </form>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <form action="/add" method="GET">
        <td>
          <h3 type="bold">4</h3>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h3>{{name3}}</h3>
          <h3>{{artist3}}:{{album3}}</h3>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h3>{{ score3 }}</h3>
        </td>

        <td>
          <input type="button" name="Add" value="Add3" id="Add3">
        </td>
      </form>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <form action="/add" method="GET">
        <td>
          <h3 type="bold">5</h3>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h3>{{name4}}</h3>
          <h3>{{artist4}}:{{album4}}</h3>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h3>{{ score4 }}</h3>
        </td>

        <td>
          <input type="button" name="Add" value="Add4" id="Add4">
        </td>
      </form>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <form action="/add" method="GET">
        <td>
          <h3 type="bold">6</h3>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h3>{{name5}}</h3>
          <h3>{{artist5}}:{{album5}}</h3>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h3>{{ score5 }}</h3>
        </td>

        <td>
          <input type="button" name="Add" value="Add5" id="Add5">
        </td>
      </form>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <form action="/add" method="GET">
        <td>
          <h3 type="bold">7</h3>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h3>{{name6}}</h3>
          <h3>{{artist6}}:{{album6}}</h3>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h3>{{ score6 }}</h3>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="button" name="Add" value="Add6" id="Add6">
        </td>
      </form>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <form action="/add" method="GET">
        <td>
          <h3 type="bold">8</h3>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h3>{{name7}}</h3>
          <h3>{{artist7}}:{{album7}}</h3>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h3>{{ score7 }}</h3>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="button" name="Add" value="Add7" id="Add7">
        </td>
      </form>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <form action="/add" method="GET">
        <td>
          <h3 type="bold">9</h3>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h3>{{name8}}</h3>
          <h3>{{artist8}}:{{album8}}</h3>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h3>{{ score8 }}</h3>
        </td>

        <td>
          <input type="button" name="Add" value="Add8" id="Add8">
        </td>
      </form>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <form action="/add" method="GET">
        <td>
          <h3 type="bold">10</h3>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h3>{{name9}}</h3>
          <h3>{{artist9}}:{{album9}}</h3>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h3>{{ score9 }}</h3>
        </td>

        <td>
          <input type="button" name="Add" value="Add9" id="Add9">
        </td>
      </form>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

I then have a python file projectfalcon.py The relevant methods are:

```
@app.route('/add', methods=['GET'])
def addingSongs():
        if request.method == 'GET':
             btnID = request.form['btn']
        if btnID == 'Add0':
            songResults[0].upVote()
            addedSongs.append(songResults[0])
            songResults.remove(0)
        if btnID == 'Add1':
            songResults[1].upVote()
            addedSongs.append(songResults[1])
            songResults.remove(1)
        return render_template('base.html')
```

So the base.html is the first page that loads. You type in an artist name to search for songs and it takes you to the search_results.html where the results are displayed. I am trying to let the user be able to click the add button and the song will then be added to a list in the projectfalcon.py file. After clicking it will also take you back to the base.html file and reload the songs that in the playlist I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have googled multiple times but may have not found the right wording. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious issue I can spot is the way you're accessing the `btn` variable. Since your form sends a `GET` request, it needs to be accessed like this:

```
btnID = request.args.get('btn', '')
```

Apart from that, I don't understand how you're storing `addedSongs` list. Flask context is limited to requests, and you shouldn't use python global namespace. You should either create a context variable (also a global in flask) or the easiest way would be to just store user data in a database.

You should take a look at [this](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) flask tutorial which is a complete guide to making a web app from scratch. Perhaps it may be of some use to get the basics cleared up and allow you to 'find the right wordings' to your problems! :)

Cheers.

Comment: So this is how I come to my problem. When I load the site it takes me to the base.html. From there I click a button and it moves to the search_results.html file and it displays some data. I want to be able to click 1 of 10 buttons and depending on which button I click it does two things. 1) it adds that song to the added song list 2) takes the user back to the base.html. So currently each button has the same name "Add" but each value changes from "Add0" to "Add1" etc. I want to be able to get which button was pressed then get the correlating song and append it to the added songs list.

Comment: Also not sure why I did not think of this earlier but I put print('testing') right below the addingSongs() function and when I click on an add button it doesnt print. Therefore, I think the method is never being called. Is there some thing wrong with my approute possible?

Comment: It's pretty hard to try and debug this way. From the things you want to do, I'd recommend understanding how the web works. How ajax, routing, redirection, forms work. It'll be much easier then to get flask to work with the way you want it to. Also, do checkout a flask tutorial to get familiarized with the basic concepts like `url_for` redirection, easier templating, array based values in forms, ajax calls etc. I'd recommend [this](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) tutorial.